# Unexpected parenthesis ')' in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I have a script that uses assembler and should run program for some asm tests

```
rem @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set REPO_PATH=%~dp0..
set INSTALL_PATH=%REPO_PATH%\bin
set TEST_DIR=%REPO_PATH%\testing_system
set TEST_LIST=%TEST_DIR%\file_list_linux.lst
set WS=%TEST_DIR%\WS
set QEMU=%REPO_PATH%\qemu\ppdl-linux-user\qemu-ppdl.exe

if not exist %QEMU% (
    echo Warning: %QEMU% not found, use %INSTALL_PATH%\qemu\qemu-ppdl
    set QEMU=%INSTALL_PATH%\qemu\qemu-ppdl
)

set assembler=%TEST_DIR%\toolset\asm.exe
set linker=%TEST_DIR%\toolset\nmc-ld.exe
set arch_flags=-nmc4

if %REPO_PATH% equ "" (set cond=1)
if %INSTALL_PATH% equ "" (set cond=1)

if cond equ 1 (
    ::echo "Usage: ./run_tests.sh  path-to-repo path-to-install-dir"
    echo Usage: run run_tests.bat only from 'testing_system' dir
    exit /b 1
)

if not exist %QEMU% (
    echo Error: %QEMU% not found
    exit /b 1
)
%assembler% %arch_flags% %TEST_DIR%\caller.asm -o caller.elf

if errorlevel 1 (
    set res=1
    echo Error: caller.asm assembler error
    exit /b 1
)

for /f "tokens=*" %%t in (%TEST_LIST%) do (
    set test_path=%TEST_DIR%\emutest\%%t
    ...
)
```

And when running cmd says `Unexpected appearance ')'` just after processing `exit /b 1 )` (before `for` statement)

I dont see where I missed any parenthesis, but I know there is a bug with them, because when i run `%assembler% %arch_flags% %TEST_DIR%\caller.asm -o caller.elf` it outputs

```
Assembler for NM6403-05 v1.75. (c) 1996-2008, RC Module. All rights reserved.
```

Could it be issued by this `(c)` or im missing something simpler?

Comment: Your variable tests like `if %REPO_PATH% equ ""` are broken, as you compare a directory with the string `""` this can't never be true. Change it to `if "%REPO_PATH%" equ ""`. And show us all your directories, I assume one contains a `)` like in `C:\Program Files(x86)`

Comment: So you're saying the `exit /b 1` runs and then you get the error? If so, it's not even getting to the `for` statement. Are you calling this batch file from another batch file?

Comment: @jeb thank you, I should fix this as well

Comment: @aphoria no, calling initially from cmd. Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the place with the issue and I have to apologize, my thoughts were incorrect and therefore my question was

This string in the `for` was incorrect

```
if exist %test_path% (goto continue)
```

just after the last line i posted in `for` and `continue` label was in the for for sure
But can you explain why cannot I use this line?
Same with no `()` around goto